# Xamarin Forms move an apk file from a server to external storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**If you can assist, please, I'm trying to move an APK file from a server to external storage.**

i Faced this issue : Android.OS.FileUriExposedException: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MyAppApks/add.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()'

```
  var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
                    var apkDirectory = new Java.IO.File(dir, "MyAppApks");
                    apkDirectory.Mkdirs();


                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var apkUrl = "http://**.**.**.**:2030/com.companyname.app1.apk";
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(apkUrl);


                    var apkFile = new Java.IO.File(apkDirectory, "com.companyname.app1.apk");
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(apkFile.AbsolutePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }


                    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                    intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {

client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "other");
        client.DownloadFile("http://**.**.**.**:2030/com.companyname.app1.apk", Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/com.companyname.app1.apk");
    }
    
    string apkFile = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/com.companyname.app1.apk";
    
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                        intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```